# Phonegap is offline - error 403 - Will it get online again? Do you know other alternatives?

Tags: android, cordova, apk, phonegap-build, phonegap

I've been using phonegap build to develop my apps since 2015. The PhoneGap team, pronounced that they won't spend their time anymore on the platform since last year, but I've been working with it since then.

Yesterday, it went offline as you can see: http://docs.phonegap.com/

Do you know other alternatives for PhoneGap Build? An online compiler for cordova without the need of android sdk or so.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know.
But I don’t think it will. They said last year that it was going to die. And now it is gone.....

We moved to macincloud.com last year and are building iOS and Android there with Cordova

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I found some cordova online compilers, most of them are paid... I think I will go with monaca.io